# Which Design Pattern I should follow when passing different data type to a library?

Tags: c#, csv, design-patterns, inversion-of-control

I am creating a CSV export library where the input data will come from different source like we can have User data to be exported to CSV and we can also have Orders data to be exported to CSV.

I am thinking of creating a FeedCSVProcesser where we will prepare CSV from the input data.

The input data will be of defined type like for users it will be UserFeed, for orders it will be of OrdersFeed and all share common interface IFeedType. We can then use DI principle and have CSV to extract data from the IFeedType using reflection and prepare CSV. Is this approach right, as I am not sure what kind of design pattern I am following or what should be there.

Please guide ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems you are doing well. Don't seek for a design pattern if you don't have any problem yet. Respect [KISS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KISS_principle) and [YAGNI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/You_aren%27t_gonna_need_it) principles. Keep following the OOD principles you've mentioned.

The most important thing in your case is making "FeedCSVProcesser" decoupled from the files it should work on. You don't want to change this class each time you have new class to be exported.

As you mentioned, dependency inversion principle is a specific form of doing so. High-level module like "FeedCSVProcesser" should not depend on low-level modules ("Orders", "Users"). Both should depend on abstractions ("IFeedType").

Comment: Hi, thanks for the guidance I guess that will suffice my requirement. I kept it simple following my above statement maintained decoupling between the classes.

Comment: That's excellent my friend. It would be great if you could mark your answer with a green V. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

As @TechWisdom said you are doing good you can carry one the process of construction with your design. Your design seems to be close to Strategy Pattern, in which depending on the value a specufic algorithm is executed.